# How to aggregate S&P 500 daily prices to five minutes prices using R?

Tags: r, time-series

The following dataset

`data("LogSPX",package = "yuima")`

contains intraday five minutes Standard and Poor 500 Log-prices data ranging from 09 July 2012 to 01 April 2015. The details part of this dataset states that the dataset is composed by a list where the element Data$allObs contains the intraday five minutes Standard and Poor cumulative Log-return data computed as Log(P_t)-Log(P_0) and P_0 is the open SPX price at 09 July 2012. Data$logdayprice contains daily SPX log prices and. Each day we have the same number of observation and the value is reported in Data$obsinday.

I'm trying to reproduce the five-minute aggregation prices using `highfrequency::aggregatePrice()` function to get the same values as in the dataset `LogSPX` so that I can apply this to other stocks.

This is how I tried to calculate

```
# load package
library(quantmod)

# download S&P 500 prices
getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "2012-07-09", to = "2015-04-01")

# select open prices
sp500 <- GSPC$GSPC.Open

# calculate aggregate prices
aggPrice <- highfrequency::aggregatePrice(sp500, alignBy = "minutes", alignPeriod = 5)
```

I get this error

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(DT) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(DT) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I think that this error is because my index doesn't include the time, so I did this

```
index(sp500) <- as.POSIXct(paste(index(sp500), "09:30"), tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

and recalculate

```
aggPrice <- highfrequency::aggregatePrice(sp500, alignBy = "minutes", alignPeriod = 5)

head(aggPrice)


                    GSPC.OPEN
2012-07-09 09:30:00   1354.66
2012-07-10 09:30:00   1352.96
2012-07-11 09:30:00   1341.40
2012-07-12 09:30:00   1341.29
2012-07-13 09:30:00   1334.81
2012-07-16 09:30:00   1356.50
```

which is the same as the original data. I'm new to time series manipulation and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSymbols` returns daily quotes, which means there are no intra-day observations to aggregate.

You can do the other way around though, aggregating the 5-minute `LogSPX` time series to daily, and check whether it matches the daily series from `getSymbols`.

Comment: thank you @kingent. I googled intraday observations, I'm a little confused between intraday, tick-by-tick and 1-minute observations. Do you know what if intraday means 1-minute observation? Do you know if it is the same as tick-by-tick?

Comment: 1-minute data means you register an observation every minute, with regular frequency. With a tick-by-tick time series, you have an observation whenever a new transaction occurs on the market, and this means that your frequency is not always constant. For example, you could have an observation 2 milliseconds after the previous one, then the next one is 4 milliseconds after that. Tick-by-tick data generally represent the highest frequency possible. Intraday data is a general term for time series with a frequency lower than one observation per day, and it includes all of the above.